# Integral involving exponential and logarithm and power

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am looking for any reference to evaluate this integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+x\right)x^{n-1}e^{-\mu x}dx,$$ where $n >1$ (non-integer) and $\mu>0$

I checked the book "Table of Integrals, Series, and Product", but I couldn't find it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: WolframAlpha.com did give a result for this (via the cloud), which may or may not be useful to you.  If I correctly transcribed it that result is $(-\mu^2)^n\mu^n \left( \,\,\,  -\pi cosec(n\pi) \Gamma(n,-\mu) \,\,\, + \,\,\, (-1)^n\Gamma(n-1)_2F_2(1,1;2,2-n;\mu)  \,\,\, + \,\,\, \Gamma(n)\left(  \,\,\, \pi cosec(n\pi)-(-1)^n ln(\mu) -(-1)^n\phi^{(n)}(0)  \,\,\, \right)  \right) $

Comment: @StephenG. Fortunately, $n$ is supposed to be a non integer number !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Probaly too long for a comment.*

As  StephenG already commented, a CAS leads to
$$\left(-\mu ^2\right)^{-n} \left(\mu  (-\mu )^n \Gamma (n-1) \, _2F_2(1,1;2,2-n;\mu
   )-\pi  \mu ^n \csc (\pi  n) \Gamma (n,-\mu )+(n-1) \Gamma (n-1) \left(\pi  \mu
   ^n \csc (\pi  n)-\log (\mu ) (-\mu )^n+(-\mu )^n \psi ^{(0)}(n)\right)\right)$$ provided that $\Re(\mu )>0\land \Re(n)>-1$ which is effectively leading to indeterminate values if $n$ is an integer.

Interesting on the other side is that, if $n$ was an integer, this would reduce 
to 
$$G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(\mu \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -n,1-n \\
 0,-n,-n
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ where appears the Meijer G function.

Comment: The Meijer G function is new to me, thanks.

Comment: @StephenG. Just nother special function ! Cheers.